# Isolate months from object array of dates and categorize according to months respective to the dates

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, set

```
let dates = {
              '2018/07/25': [['r','red'], ['b','blue']],
              '2018/07/26': [['a','apple'], ['o','orange']],
              '2018/08/01': [['d','deer'], ['l','lion']]
            }
```

The newObject expected is:

```
newObject = {
             '2018/07':{
                         '2018/07/25': [['r','red'], ['b','blue']],
                         '2018/07/26': [['a','apple'], ['o','orange']]
                       },
             '2018/08':{
                         '2018/08/01': [['d','deer'], ['l','lion']]
                       }
```

My code so far:

```
let newObject = {};

Object.keys(dates).forEach((onedate, index) => {
    let monthdate = onedate.slice(0,7)
    newObject[monthdate] = {[onedate] : [...dates[onedate]]};       
});
```

The output of above code:

```
newObject = {
             '2018/07':{
                         '2018/07/26': [['a','apple'], ['o','orange']]
                       },
             '2018/08':{
                         '2018/08/01': [['d','deer'], ['l','lion']]
                       }
```

The last date overwrites the upper objects in the same loop

Is it possible to do this operation in a single loop function?
Do I have to use Sets?

Comment: btw, why do you spread the values of the array? just to remove the same object reference? the inner arrays have still the same reference.

Comment: @NinaScholz what do you mean? which reference?

Comment: i mean this `[...dates[onedate]]`.

Comment: actually, that dates[onedate] is a Set. So, i have to parse it.
How can I differentiate a normal object from a set?

Comment: with a check `instanceof`.

Comment: i mean, how can i denote that a given object is a set while writing in some posts or comments?

Comment: are you talking about this [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) or something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to solve this problem, some maybe even including `Set`.

However, using your code as a starting point, the answer is pretty simple: Don't overwrite `newObject[monthdate]` if it already exists.

```
let newObject = {};

Object.keys(dates).forEach((onedate, index) => {
    let monthdate = onedate.slice(0,7)
    if (!newObject[monthdate]) {
        newObject[monthdate] = {};
    }
    newObject[monthdate][onedate] = [...dates[onedate]];       
});
```

Comment: the check for to overwrite or not works fine... thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd write it using `Array.reduce` to construct the final object.

```js
var dates = {
  '2018/07/25': [
    ['r', 'red'],
    ['b', 'blue']
  ],
  '2018/07/26': [
    ['a', 'apple'],
    ['o', 'orange']
  ],
  '2018/08/01': [
    ['d', 'deer'],
    ['l', 'lion']
  ]
}

var result = Object.keys(dates).reduce((mem, cur) => {
  var key = cur.slice(0, 7);
  mem[key] = { ...(mem[key] || {}),
    [cur]: dates[cur]
  };
  return mem;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Your code is not producing correct result, because you forgot to merge the properties when adding new properties. See, when you are doing `{ [onedate] : [...dates[onedate]] }`, here you need to merge the old entries also like I did below.

```
newObject[monthdate] = {...newObject[monthdate], [onedate] : [...dates[onedate]]};
```

Your code after the fix:

```js
var dates = {
  '2018/07/25': [
    ['r', 'red'],
    ['b', 'blue']
  ],
  '2018/07/26': [
    ['a', 'apple'],
    ['o', 'orange']
  ],
  '2018/08/01': [
    ['d', 'deer'],
    ['l', 'lion']
  ]
}

var newObject = {};

Object.keys(dates).forEach((onedate, index) => {
  var monthdate = onedate.slice(0, 7)
  newObject[monthdate] = { ...newObject[monthdate],
    [onedate]: [...dates[onedate]]
  };
});

console.log(newObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the entries of the object and take a simple guard operator, a [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) for checking if a property has been set (is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)) or not ([falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)). If not take an object as default value. Then assign the property.

Truthy values are objects, arrays, not empty strings or all numbers without zero or `NaN`.

```js
let dates = { '2018/07/25': [['r', 'red'], ['b', 'blue']], '2018/07/26': [['a', 'apple'], ['o', 'orange']], '2018/08/01': [['d', 'deer'], ['l', 'lion']] },
    newObject = {};

Object.entries(dates).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    let monthdate = key.slice(0, 7);
    newObject[monthdate] = newObject[monthdate] || {};
    newObject[monthdate][key] = value;
});

console.log(newObject);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: i'm working on large numbers of similar type of data. your code ran at ~1 ms whereas others ran about ~0.5 ms.
your code's logic is clean

Comment: the logical or is a bit slower than an explicit check with an `if` statement. a simple `for` loop with an index would be faster than `forEach` ...